# CakePHP setFlash() severity ('good'/'bad') not working?

Tags: php, cakephp

When using `$this->Session->setFlash('Some bog standard message.')` in my controller the flash message shows up correctly as expected. The default styling is red and looks like an error. [In the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages) it illustrates that the severity of the flash message can be changed by passing a string to the `$key` parameter. The documentation uses 'good' and 'bad' but when adjusting the code to the following:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('A good message!', 'default', array(), 'good');
```

There is no Flash message at all, not even the default red one. I am having to do this to get the desired effect:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('A good message!', 'default', array('class' => 'message success'));
```

Is this broken or am I missing something?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, just as the docs describe, when using the `key` parameter you have to use the appropriate `key` in the view too, ie `$this->Session->flash('good')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation of how the book references you could do it:**

If you want the color to change, you'll need to style them differently.   The key they reference in the book just shows you how you can write different flash messages - it has nothing to do with the actual styling of the message - just which one gets written where:

```
//Controller
// set a bad message.
$this->Session->setFlash('Something bad.', 'default', array(), 'bad');

// set a good message.
$this->Session->setFlash('Something good.', 'default', array(), 'good');

// in a view.
echo $this->Session->flash('good');
echo $this->Session->flash('bad');
```

So - if you wanted to style it different, you could wrap the "good" with a div or something and give it a class that would then style it differently.   Use your imagination - but the point is, the key doesn't change it's visual style, but is a key referencing WHICH key it is/should be written.

**How I do it - using an element and a parameter to change visual styles:**

Below is how I set up my alert messages - this uses Twitter Bootstrap classes and icons which change how the alert looks depending on the 'type' parameter I send to my "notifications" element.  Of course, it can be edited to suite your needs, but you should get the idea of another route you can go.

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('This is my success message'),
    'notifications', array('type'=>'success'));

$this->Session->setFlash(__('This is my failure message'),
    'notifications', array('type'=>'fail'));

//'notifications' element
<?php
$icon = 'icon-ok-sign';
if(!empty($type)) {
    switch($type) {
        case 'fail':
            $type='danger';
        case 'danger':
            $icon = 'icon-warning-sign';
            break;
        case 'info':
            $icon = 'icon-info';
            break;
        case 'success':
            $icon = 'icon-ok-sign';
            break;
        case 'error':
            $type = 'danger';
            $icon = 'icon-warning-sign';
            break;
    }
}

?>
<div class="alert alert-<?php echo $type ?>">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <i class="<?php echo $icon ?>"></i> <?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Goodness me I did just misunderstand it! Ok, I get it now and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I personally create a view element for alerts, and then pass a class name in my `setFlash()` call.

```
<!-- View/Elements/flash.ctp -->
<div class="alert alert-<?php echo $class; ?>">
  <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
</div>
```

And then set your flash messages in your controllers as follows:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Lorem ipsum.', 'flash', array('class' => 'success'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) I don't believe this answered his question of "why it's not working", and 2) It seems exactly how I already explained it.